# How to change default apache login/password pop-up box to custom using js/html/php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache

i would like to know is it possible to change apache default login box to custom visualized/modified using javascript/html/php ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom form using [mod_auth_form](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html) as long as you have access to add the modules necessary. Basically you would design the form, then setup the parameters.

Most people will usually create a custom form handled by a language like `PHP` where they will check a database for a login match then pass logged-in variables to the users via sessions. This method would allow more control because you can actually set access levels. Whereas with `mod_auth*` you're either in or not.